# Creating multiple daemons in C Linux and communicating between them

Tags: c, linux, process, daemon, communication

I am working on Linux Ubuntu to create daemon processes. I have referred the following tutorial to learn about the basic implementation of a daemon code using fork and setid:

http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

**I have an application where I have to create multiple daemon processes and communicate between them.**

For example: 
 **I have 3 source files and I would like to make them as 3 different daemon processes**. And I have functions defined in these source files, which I would like to call from main() or from other source files.

1. **How exactly should I create multiple daemon processes i.e each individual source file acts as a separate daemon process ?**
   (I might be wrong here but I was planning to create threads to the functions of these files function, where this function will have its own PID and then I do fork and setid and the rest process to create a daemon here, which might create individual multiple daemons ? )
2. **How should I manage communication between these daemon processes ?** 
   For example: If I want to call some function from source file, and if that source file is a daemon process, then how should I call a function from that daemon process ?

I am searching the internet about multiple daemon processes and their intercommunication, but it would be very great if someone can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Look up "fork and exec" and follow one of the many recipes.

Comment: Write three different programs, each with a main. When you execute these become three processes. You can transfer data between these processes using message queues.

Comment: Both the solutions suggested above worked correctly.
 I created separate programs each with a main, and made each one of them as separate daemon process. Along with the use of signals I can interrupt the processes and do data transfer using ZeroMQ. 
The method with fork and execvp works too to create multiple daemon processes.
Thanks for the suggestion.. It WORKED

Answer (score 0):

If you are target linux, I will recommend you to let the demon feature be handle by the init system (systemd for example).

To communicate between your programs, you can use a named pipe https://linux.die.net/man/4/fifo.

Comment: Hello, 
I shall look into pipe for communication. But my doubt is how to create my source files/functions as daemon processes ? If I have some code in the main file or some function in the main then I am able to create a daemon process, but I have multiple source files(which have many function declarations), how to make every source file or some functions as individual daemon processes ? Thanks for helping.